# change image in partial from js.erb without refresh of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

ruby v 1.9.3p194
rails v 3.1.3

I am very new to ruby/rails/js I have been seaching for a while to no avail. How do I update both images from capture_photo.js.erb?

I am using js to capture an image from a web camera and set it as the users avatar. The image is being stored in patient.photo_uid.

I display the image in 2 partials and want both images to be updated once saved. I think I want to do it from my capture_photo.js.erb

```
//relevant sidbar.html.haml:
  %a#user_sidebar_image{href: "javascript:void(0)"}
  = image_tag user_avatar_url(current_patient, "thumb")

//relevant _patient_info.html.haml:
  %img.img-polaroid{:src => "#{photo}", alt: "Patient avatar image"}


//relevant capture_photo.js.erb:
  <% if @success == true %>
    //I want to set picture here
```

Comment: Please include your question in the text as well.

Comment: Am I asking wrong? Are there any suggestions to do it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... The answer is..

```
 <% if @success == true %>
 $('#user_sidebar_image > img').attr('src', "<%= @patient.photo.try(:url) %>")
 $('.thumbnail-container > img').attr('src', "<%= @patient.photo.try(:url) %>")
```